# how to put / reference a lock beside a private content

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Currently, using Ektron CMS, i am trying to place a lock.jpg beside a protected / private content, which needs the user to login, if the link is clicked.

I am not sure how to start or go by this ?

Any idea or snippet of achieving this will be grateful.

Thanks,
Ron.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to a different CMS, seriously.

Comment: Well, all i am trying to get to do is, to place a lock jpg beside a protected content, sitewide, and since being a newbie, am not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Does it have to be a .jpg?  How are the links displayed?  Could you use a font with a lock character in it?

Comment: no, any icon in the viewable format, be it a .png,.gif,...but it seems Bill Cava from ektron himself, gave the excellent solution on resolving thanks. Thanks Chris, anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentData object has an IsPrivate property you can look at. In the latest (v8.5), I would do the following. In code behind:

```
    ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager();
    ContentCriteria criteria = new ContentCriteria();
    criteria.AddFilter(ContentProperty.FolderId,
                       CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo,
                       folderId);

    List<ContentData> list = contentManager.GetList(criteria);
    Listview1.DataSource = list;
    Listview1.DataBind();
```

For using statements, you'll need the following:

```
    using Ektron.Cms;
    using Ektron.Cms.Common;
    using Ektron.Cms.Framework;

    using Ektron.Cms.Content;
    using Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content;
```

Then in the ASP.NET Template, I would use a standard ASP.NET ListView Server Control:

```
    <asp:listview ID="Listview1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <li><img src="<%#Eval("IsPrivate") %>.jpg" /><%#Eval("Title") %></li>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:listview>
```

That'll get you heading in the right direction. For more information on the v8.5 Framework API, see this webinar http://www.ektron.com/Resources/Webinars/Framework-API/

Comment: Thanks Bill, Wow, the perfect solution from Ektron's CTO himself. !!! I will try this out, and thanks again.